# insert(graph,x,y) in an undirected graph(adjacency list) already containing (y,x)

Tags: graphs

Good day.

In an undirected graph, if edge(x,y) is in the graph, (y,x) is also there.

Considering that I use adjacency lists to implement my graph, should insert(graph,x,y) do nothing if graph already contains (y,x)?

Thank you.

Comment: *Should do* according to whom? I define insert(graph, x , y) to be the function that destroys the universe, that's what it should do according to me. Can you prove me wrong?
Correctness in a vacuum doesn't exist. What do you want to do and why?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you share more context about how you plan to evaluate answers?  The question sounds like a matter of opinion.  What are your thoughts?  What approaches have you considered, and what criteria do you think are relevant in your particular situation?

Comment: How you implement it is entirely up to you. Use whatever gives you the best (for you) trade-off between efficiency and ease of use.

Comment: @quicksort oh boy ...

Comment: @D.W Thank you for the welcome
I was really waiting for a validation of what I think is true; if (x,y) exists, (y,x) exists. I have to admit that my question was resulted by some confusion from the implementation and specific data structure I used (unordered_map in C++).
Eventually, and since I also add a weight on insertions, the case of inserting (x,y) while (y,x) exists become nothing but a potential update of the weight of that edge, and the operation should be in constant time so my problem is practically solved.

Comment: @David Richerby great advice I'll keep that in mind thanks.

Comment: Yes, in an undirected graph, if edge $(x,y)$ exists, then edge $(y,x)$ exists.